# How to move attribute expresion inside function and hide remove attribute only? React

Tags: reactjs

I have logic for adding attributes. If an array has less than 1 item add attribute `disabled: true` else nothing.

```
<button {...(array.length < 1 ? { disabled: true } : {})}> Submit </button>
```

And this works fine, but I need to move this code to some function `useCallback()` or whatever and move the logic to a function.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something like this

```
export default function App() {
  const [btnDisabled, setBtnDisabled] = useState(true);
  const [myArray, setMyArray] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setMyArray([]);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (myArray.length >= 1) {
      setBtnDisabled(false);
    }
  }, [myArray]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button disabled={btnDisabled}> Submit </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

you can try it here (I guess it would depend also on how your array data get changed)
here is the link to try it
https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-rhodes-i2kttc?file=/src/App.js:69-556